# 学校まで行くバスは、一時間に一本しかなかったので、学校にときどき遅刻をしてしまうことがありました。

Tags: meaning

> 学校まで行くバスは、一時間に一本しかなかったので、学校にときどき遅刻をしてしまうことがありました。

Hello, I don't know what the 1 book is doing in the middle of this sentence form my 新完全マスター語彙日本語能力試験N3 book.

My meaning: "On the way to school it takes 1 hour and I have nothing to do but read one book on the way there."

I know it's wrong, but what else can you do with a book other than read it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know its wrong, but what else can you do with a book other than read it??

Books have many use cases, it's only limited by your inspiration! But in this case, 本 is not a book. It's a "counter". [Check out these questions and answers.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=count%20%E6%9C%AC)

一時間 is one hour - it's a way to count. Likewise, 一本 is one "bus coming on that route" - a way to count too.

It's confusing because 本 means book, you're correct. But when we attach バス, you can forget about the book.